# Notation issue in a paper on loop quantum gravity/geometrodynamics

Tags: tensor-calculus, notation, loop-quantum-gravity

I was reading a paper and I came across some notation that confused me. This was concerning the extrinsic curvature tensor defined as $K_{ab} = \frac{\mu}{2}K^i_{(a}K^i_{b)}$. I am normally comfortable with tensor indices, but the placement of the brackets seemed strange. This was not a typo, as later on, similar notation was used for another tensor $\mathcal{K}_{ab} = \mu^2K^i_{[a}E^i_{b]}$. Is this a standard notation used in these areas, and what does it refer to?

Answer (score 2):

This is indeed not a typo: the round brackets mean [symmetrization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_tensor) over the enclosed indices, the square ones mean [anti-symmetrization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antisymmetric_tensor). This notation is not specific to LQG/geometrodynamics, but is a standard one (as acknowledged by the linked wikipedia page on antisymmetric tensors).

Answer (score 2):

Yes: parentheses and brackets are standard notation. They mean symmetrisation and anti-symmetrisation:
$$
\begin{aligned}
A_{(\mu\nu)}\equiv\frac{1}{2}(A_{\mu\nu}+A_{\nu\mu})\\
A_{[\mu\nu]}\equiv\frac{1}{2}(A_{\mu\nu}-A_{\nu\mu})
\end{aligned}
$$
and similar relations for higher-order tensors. One should note that the factor $\frac12$ is sometimes omitted by some authors.